# Filtering of structured array via bit-wise operation (bitmask) on column data

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a structured array. One column (`event_type`) is a bitfield. I would like to filter the data via the `event_type`.

Previously I used `filter()` but it produces a `list` that would need to be back converted into an array, and I would need to preserve `dtype` with column names and other stuff from original array.

`event_type` is a name of the event, and `namespaces['event_types']['event_types']` is a map from name ta an `int` value with appropriate bit set to `1` - the mask.

Old code was something like:

```
event_type ='new_best'
event_type = rep.namespaces['event_types']['event_types'][event_type]
data = zip(rep.get_data('best_age'), rep.get_data('event_type'))
data = filter( lambda datum : int(datum[1]) & int(event_type), data)
data = list(zip(*data))[0]
```

While refactoring I invented a function to work with `numpy` types:

```
def filter_stats(self, event_type):
  event_type = int(self.namespaces['event_types']['event_types'][event_type])
  data = self.data['stats']
  mask = np.bitwise_and(data['event_type'], event_type) #make a "bitwise" mask
  mask = np.logical_and(mask, True)            #convert it into logical values
  #print(event_type, data['event_type'], mask)
  return data[ mask ]
```

Now I can call `filter_stats('new_best')['best_age']` for the same functionality.

My questions:

1. Is this the good approach? Or is there a better way to filter the data.
2. Can it be more concise? I especially don't like converting the `mask` from `int` to `bool` types, but I cannot get my head around how to skip it.

Comment: this is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JoranBeasley do you know if the mods can move it or I need to delete and repost? I figured out the "new code" while writing the question on how can I filter it. That's why it looks like this =/ I am mainly interested in 2. but maybe I went wrong all the way.

Comment: I suspect a mod will see it and move it ...

Comment: Are you wedded to the `numpy` structured array approach?  If not, I strongly recommend checking out [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) for working with non-numerical data.

Comment: @DSM but I have all numerical data. I will check it out none-the-less. Maybe will be feasible for future projects, but I filter data to produce plots in `matplotlib`. I just print some run-time stats for different events.

Comment: @luk32: if you had all numerical data you wouldn't need your `event_type` mapping.. you have categorical data you've given numerical labels to. :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can merge the two lines into:

```
mask = (data['event_type'] & event_type).astype(bool)
```